# Weird failure in cucumber tests -> undefined method `before_non_js'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber

Out of nowhere today (possibly after a bundle update), all my Cukes started failing with this error:

```
Scenario: Creating a bus
  undefined method `before_non_js' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@busables/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
  /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@busables/bundler/gems/cucumber-rails-192768e5dc29/lib/cucumber/rails/database.rb:16:in `before_non_js'
  /Users/davidtuite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@busables/bundler/gems/cucumber-rails-192768e5dc29/lib/cucumber/rails/hooks/active_record.rb:15:in `Before'
```

Anyone got any idea where it comes from? I've never heard of `before_non_js` before, it doesn't exist anywhere in my project at least.

All unit tests still pass and I can click through the site just fine. It's a Rails 3.1.1 app with cucumber 1.1.1.

I tried searching the cucumber issues on github but nothing comes up.

Comment: I had this problem once... here's what I remember.  The problem had something to do with a bug in my server-side validation code. I never saw the bug when I was testing manually because I was also running the client_side_validations gem.  So, when testing manually I was avoiding hitting some particular path in the server-side validation code.  When running cucumber though, I hit that path, because the client_side_validations weren't active. If you are running any client side validations, turn those off, then try manually going through this code path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New "feature" of cucumber that isn't being initialized properly for some reason.  Adding this to env.rb fixes it for now:

```
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy   = :truncation
```